# Is there any way to pass variables from bash script to Jenkinsfile without using extra plugins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to use variables declared in bash script in my Jenkinsfile (jenkins pipeline) without using extra plugins like EnvInject plugin
please help, any idea will be appreciated

Comment: You could execute the script and have them create environment variables which you can use inside the Jenkinsfile.

Answer (score 1):

you need to output those variables to a file like `Property/Yaml` file. Then use pipeline step [readProperties / readYaml](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#pipeline-utility-steps) to read into Map in Jenkinsfile.

```
steps {
    sh'''
      ...

      AA=XXX
      BB=YYY

      set > vars.prop
    '''

    script {
        vars = readProperties file: 'vars.prop'

        env << vars // merge vars into env

        echo 'AA='+ env['AA']
    }
}
```

Comment: Cant you just have them stored as environment variables?

Comment: i have bash script that contains a lot of vars, so i can't declare these vars manually, if there is a way to create pipeline env vars which will contain the values of my vars declared in the bash script  i will be happy

Comment: There is no straight way can do that.  One way is like what I did above. You can add `set > vars.prop` to the end of your bash script.  then execute the bash script as `sh  './<your script file>'`

Answer (score 0):

I have done it with something like this, you can store the variables inside Shell into a file inside workspace and then you are out of shell block, read the file in groovy to load the key value pair into your environment

Something like:

```
            def env_file = "${WORKSPACE}/shell_env.txt"
            echo ("INFO: envFileName = ${env_file}")
            def read_env_file = readFile env_file
            def lines = read_env_file.readLines()
            lines.each { String line ->
                def object = line.split("=")
                env.object[0] = object[1]
            }
```